# Can the server admin of Azure SQL authenticate via Azure AD only? I don't like plain passwords without MFA

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

For security reasons I'd like to only connect to my Azure SQL database via Azure AD authentication. Azure AD auth works just fine for any new users I add, but still the server admin (the one set-up during deployment of the resource) remains authenticated only by a password.

[See step #9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal#create-a-single-database)

Is there a way that even the server admin is Azure Ad authenticated ONLY?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on the roadmap, but an ETA has not been publicly announced. Currently the SQL Admin user is the only way gain access to the server if the AAD Admin is unavailable.

You can effectively disallow logins using that account (except in the necessary scenario where the Resource owner needs to reset the password) by generating and forgetting a new password for the SQL Admin user.  EG

```
declare  @sql nvarchar(500) = concat('alter login sqladminuser with password = ''', cast(newid() as varchar(50)), '''')
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do hope this comes soon, though. Is there a character limit? Can I concat the newid() function 10x?